# Какую структуру данных использовать?

Tags: java, data-structures, persistence

Добрый день

Мне нужно решить данную задачу: **имеется последовательность целых чисел, которые в совокупности представляют собой первую версию последовательности.**

Я должен изменять один из элементов, получая таким образом следующую версию последовательности.
Менять можно любую версию, как и **обращаться к любой из существующих** для вывода i-того элемента k-той версии.

Т.е., насколько я понимаю, мне нужно использовать структуру с полной персистентностью, только вот с высоты своего невысокого полета я не могу определить, какую именно и каким образом я смогу обращаться к предыдущим версиям.

Можно ли создать массив из массивов, чтобы при вызове метода во внешнем массиве создавался внутренний, базирующийся на одном из предыдущих?

Подойдет ли `List<int[]>`?

Благодарен за помощь

Comment: В идеале вам нужно реализовать паттерн copy-on-write, я не могу подсказать конкретной эффективной имплементации, но наверняка одна из первых найденных статей расскажет вам сам принцип организации таких элементов.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List подойдет, если длина последовательности неизменна. Я бы написал класс, в котором реализовал бы методы изменения одного из элементов с автоматическим созданием и добавлением в список новой версии последовательности. Примерно так:

```
public class Data {
  List<int[]> sequences = new ArrayList<>();

  public int getElem(int version, int element) {
    //проверки на выходы за границы коллекций
    return sequences.get(version)[element];
  }

  public void changeElem(int version, int element, int newValue) {
    //меняем указанный элемент в указанной версии и кладем результат в новую последнюю версию
    int[] ver = sequences.get(version);
    int[] newVer = new int[ver.length];
    System.arraycopy(ver, 0, newVer, 0, ver.length);
    newVer[element] = newValue;
    sequences.add(newVer);
}
```